# Why is this list empty

Tags: list, scala, match

I want to make a function in scala that uses "match ... case" to double the values of a list.

For example:

```
doubleList(List(2,1,4,5))
//> res0: List[Int] = List(4, 2, 8, 10)
```

I wrote this function:

```
def doubleList(xs: List[Int]): List[Int] =
    xs match {
      case y :: ys =>
        y * 2; doubleList(ys);
      case Nil => xs;
    }
```

But I get an empty list as the result:

```
//> res0: List[Int] = List()
```

Can anyone teel me what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Any reason, why you don't just use `map(_ * 2)`?

Comment: Yes, I am required to use specificly "match ... case".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `;` closes the statement and effectively throws away the result, use `::` instead to create a new `List` with the result of `y * 2` and `doubleList(ys)`

```
def doubleList(xs: List[Int]): List[Int] =
  xs match {
    case y :: ys =>
      y * 2 :: doubleList(ys)
    case Nil => xs
  }
```

P.S. you don't have to put a `;` at the end of a line in scala.

Comment: Oh, I didn't know about that ; closes the statement. Thanks for your answer, worked just great.